# Visual Studio 2010 current line highlight

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've got the Productivity Power Tools and have set the Highlight Current Line option on and set the colour to blue in the Font and Colours section.  However, every time I start VS the line highlight is a white colour, it only changes if I go to Tools -> Options -> Font and Colours and hit OK.  Anyone know why this is as it can get very annoying!

Comment: do you have any other extensions/add-ins installed?

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed? It can also highlight the current line.

Comment: Nope, no other extensions and ONLY the highlight current line enabled.  Looks like it's a bug as there have been other people having the same problem.  Haven't got resharper installed, seems like a lot of money to spend just to highlight the current line!

Comment: @jrummell thank you, that resharper problem has being bugging me for so long. I just found the solution under tools>options>fonts and colors> Resharper Current Line Highlight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be an actual bug in Pro Power Tools. First, make sure you have the latest version installed (uninstall the old version). Then ask this question on the Q&A section here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef